# Github API Repository permissions

Tags: github, oauth-2.0, git-merge, github-api, git-pull

I have a crazy complicated authentication process that I'm trying to wrap my brain around with this and I just need to be pointed in the right direction. I am building a website for Startup Weekend and we are trying to incorporate github repository management and don't know where to start. In it's simple form I need to give permissions for the website to access my github repo, then the website will allow another person (who is logged in with github) to be able to modify and push the code back up.

The simple way to do it is through adding that person outside of the site to the repository. However, it would be really cool if the site was able to manage it. Is this even possible to do? My closest assumption is pulling the code through the API, allowing a person access to the repo that is now downloaded, and then doing a merge through the API.

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction so we can win this thing! (If no one is able to answer I will keep digging and answer it for other people.) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The [GitHub OAuth API](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/) page is a good start.

You can see it used in a project like [`thephpleague/oauth2-client`](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client) in [`Provider/GithubTest.php`](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client/blob/374c3d41db38d1d2d4071c58fa5515f58ea4566e/test/src/Provider/GithubTest.php).